Which file related to resetting the password takes the data from the .env
I need to insert the email data that goes in the .env, directly in the code and not in the .env. However, I can't figure out which file is getting these settings.
I am using the following line of code just like the laravel 10 documentation
$status = Password::sendResetLink(
  $request->only('email')
);

Can anyone tell me which file contains the .env settings to send this email?

Simply testing email server using

Mailtrap account login or create new account
https://mailtrap.io/signin

dashboard image.
You can view the dashboard. Have you not viewed the project -> Create a new project. click setting button action have
sample image
Go Code Samples php select dropdown click and select laravel9+
configuration copy image
Right side copy button can copy the configuration and paste .env file
configuration image
Change this confgurations

Do not post the code as an image. The link can be depreciated after some time. Read How do I write a good answer?

Then, if we want to show a UI, how do we show it?

I hope you will understand the difference between a Code and UI and What OP asked and what you answered is two different thing

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Usually, email config can be found at config/mail.php
return [
    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'url' => env('MAIL_URL'),
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN'),
        ],
    ],

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],
    
    // Other mail configuration settings
];

Laravel email configs
